# How to establish a constraint in GAMS for specific example

Tags: parameters, set, constraints, equation, gams-math

Can anyone help me figure out how to introduce these constraints in GAMS software?
Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko5De.jpg)

Xijkl = 0, i ={3}, j={1,2}, for all k that belong to K, for all l that belong to  L

Xijkl = 0, i ={2}, j={3}, for all k that belong to K, for all l that belong to  L

Answer (score 0):

Here some insights:
What you described are specific values for a variable X rather than an equation. So:

1- Define the sets:

```
sets
i /i1,i2,i3,i4/ *assuming 4 elements in each set
j /j1,j2,j3,j4/
k /k1,k2,k3,k4/
l /l1,l2,l3,l4/
```

2- Define the variable:

```
Positive variables
X(i,j,k,l)
```

3- Define the specific combination of indexes when X is fixed to 0.

```
X.fx(i,j,k,l)$(ord(i)=3 and (ord(j)=2 or ord(j)=3))=0;
X.fx(i,j,k,l)$(ord(i)=2 and ord(j)=3)=0;
```